# Object oriented design - design furniture system in an extendable way

Tags: oop

I got this question while interviewing and I didn't know how to answer it properly. The question is that we got a furniture system which we can manage different furniture. Each furniture has its own `material` (ex: wood, iron) and `name`, `type` (ex: chair, desk, table).

For each furniture, we can call `isFireApproved()` and `getWeight()`.
First, I draw the base class on the top called `Furniture` and `Material`. Under the Furniture, I put different types of furniture like table, chair and did the same thing to the material class. Like the following diagram.

Then, I said if we want to produce a piece of new furniture like `woodchair`, we can create a new class called `woodchair` that inherits `wood` class and `chair` class.

[image]

Then the interviewer asked what if we have thousands of different furniture? What could possibly happen in this architecture and how to solve it? I basically stuck here and answered we could make a general class, pass the furniture type and material into the instance.

For example:

```
wood_iron_wardrobe = CommonFurniture(type=[Wardrobe], materials=[Wood, Iron])
```

In the constructor, we utilize these parameters to create a new item of furniture. Based on the face of the interview, I thought I didn't answer it in the right direction. Is there any suggestion for this design? Or is there any recommendation for learning OOD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, as you wrote "we can create a new class called woodchair that inherits wood class and chair class", I think, he didn't like the idea to create a new class for each combination of furniture and material because the large number of possible classes. In such a case, people may prefer composition over inheritance. For instance a `Furniture` has a member/property of type `Material`. So you would need `m` concrete classes for `Furniture` and `n` classes for Material. With inheritance you would need `m x n` classes for the concrete products.

Also `Material` is usually static, you would rarely change anything in `Material`. And multiple inheritance is not possible in many languages. In Java it may look like this:

```java
enum Material (
   WOOD (...),
   IRON (...)
)

class Furniture {
   Material material;
}

Furniture woodChair = new Chair(Material.WOOD);
Furniture ironChair = new Chair(Material.IRON);
```

This is just an example, one can implement this in a better way.

Comment: And I realize this is called `decorator` pattern.